# For the Exacting Query psionic effect from the Telepathic Contact discipline, are responses given vocally or telepathically?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, telepathy, mystic

The [2017 UA Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) has access to various Psionic Disciplines. One of the psionic effects of the Telepathic Contact discipline is an option called [Exacting Query](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=26), whose description states:

> ***Exacting Query (2 psi).*** As an action, you target one creature you can communicate with via telepathy. The target must make an Intelligence saving throw. On a failed save, the target truthfully answers one question you ask it via telepathy. On a successful save, the target is unaffected, and you can’t use this ability on it again until you finish a long rest. A creature is immune to this ability if it is immune to being charmed.

This question is asked via telepathy, but is it answered via telepathy or vocally?

The Mystic's telepathy (gained at level 2) seems to be described as only operating one way (from the Mystic to any creature the Mystic can see within 120 feet). So does this imply that the answer to an Exacting Query would be vocal?

Answer (score 6):

### It is likely answered telepathically

Not only does the feature require you to target a creature you can communicate with telepathically but the phrase:

> On a failed save, the target truthfully answers one question you ask it via telepathy.

Can be parsed so that "via telepathy" applies to the answering of your question, or the entire phrase in general. (For example, the sentence "They answer one question you ask without realizing it")

Additionally, remember that the Mystic is Unearthed Arcana so it is not as heavily edited as other things in the game, this means intent is a good indicator of how something should work and that the Rules As Written can be unclear at times. This feature is specifically for the Discipline of "Telepathic Contact" so it would make sense for the entire event to happen telepathically.

This also fits well with the ideas of the Order of the Awakened which Telepathic Contact is a discipline for:

> Mystics dedicated to the Order of the Awakened seek to unlock the full potential of the mind. By transcending the physical, the Awakened hope to attain a state of being focused on pure intellect and mental energy

The use of telepathy would transcend the physical and use the potential of the mind.

RAW, it is unclear what part of the phrase "via telepathy" applies to, so it would be left up to a GM.

Comment: Supported by your arguments, the feature does suggest that it is essentially allowing the mystic to pull information directly from a target's mind.